# read file as a set of lines in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm more familiar with Python than Perl so I'm trying to figure out the equivalent of this Python snippet:

```
lines = {line.rstrip() for line in open('file.txt')}  # method 1
lines = set(map(str.rstrip, open('file.txt')))  # method 2, same result
```

This returns a `set`, which is like a hash in Perl, except there are only keys (no values).  The above code is a bit naughty since it leaks the file handle, but the most popular version of Python uses reference counting for its garbage collector so the leak gets cleaned up right away.

I know Perl has a reputation for compact code so there's hopefully some fairly easy way to do something similar.  The best I've found so far is something like

```
my %lines;
open(FILE, "file.txt") or die "couldn't open file.txt";
while ( <FILE> ) {
 chomp;
 $lines{$_}=1;
}
close(FILE);
```

Without resorting to CPAN, is this more or less the best one can do?  I was hoping to do something like this but can't figure out how

```
my @lines = <open('file.txt')>; # treat open as expression that returns a file handle
# Perl uses ref counting GC too, I think, so file is now closed
my %lines;
@lines{@lines} = 1; # I think this works??
```

Comment: follow-up question ... is it possible to write a sub that works the way I wish open worked?

Comment: Of course it's possible. `sub get_fh { open my $fh, '<', $_[0] or die "..."; return $fh; }`

Comment: ([lexical file handles](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl56delta#File-and-directory-handles-can-be-autovivified), unlike bareword ones, are closed when their refcount goes to 0, and are easier to pass to functions/return from/store in different variables/etc.. Aside from the predefined ones like `STDIN`, you really shouldn't be using bareword handles)

Comment: Oh, that's interesting!  I didn't know about that difference!

Answer (score 3):

@ikegami shows in the comments something that I'd do until I had a reason not to. You can populate `@ARGV` inside a program:

```
local @ARGV = ( ... );
my %hash = map { s/\s+\z//r, 1 } <>;
```

You said you wanted a subroutine, but that's nothing special:

```
sub read_lines {
    local @ARGV = @_;
    my %hash = map { s/\s+\z//r, 1 } <>;
    return \%hash;
    }
```

But, you don't have to fool around with `@ARGV`. I'm not especially fond of saving typing:

```
sub read_lines {
    my %hash;
    foreach my $file ( @_ ) {
        open my $fh, '<:encoding(...)', $file or next; #maybe warn?
        $hash{ s/\s+\z//r }++ while <$fh>; 
        }
    return \%hash;
    }
```

I think you're looking for some trick, but you basically have to do all the steps. And, remember that Perl's reputation for compact code goes back to the day when C was the alternative. That Python now exists and is also a popular high-level language means that Perl's "compactness" isn't relatively compact anymore. And, just as a note, Perl is actually going backward in this regard as we add various boilerplate items to the usual setup. The one-liners are still as small as ever, but you don't like @ikegami's suggestions :)

Comment: Should your second `read_lines` sub have a `return %hash` too?

Answer (score 2):

```perl
use File::Slurper qw( read_lines );

my %set = map { $_ => 1 } for read_lines( "file.txt" );
```

or

```perl
use File::Slurper qw( read_lines );

my %set; ++$set{ $_ } for read_lines( "file.txt" );
```

Comment: that does look much better but I did say no CPAN allowed :)

Comment: You also said this was about Perl's ability to write concise code. Leveraging already-written code is a huge part of that. So I ignored the nonsense requirement to avoid CPAN. (Well, I would have if I had noticed it.) Besides, noone said you had to get File::Slurper from CPAN. Feel free to grab if from its repo on GitHub. You further undermined yourself a moment later when you asked if a sub could help. What do you think `read_lines` is?

Comment: Indeed, read_lines is a sub.  But I'm not asking "has a sub that does what I want already been written by someone?".  Instead I'm asking "how would I go about writing it?".  I just looked at the source code and it mostly looks as I would naively expect.  I suppose that means the original code I posted is reasonably idiomatic, given my "nonsense" wish to avoid libs not in the core?

Comment: Code reviews belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ But I'd avoid global vars in favour of lexicals. I'd avoid 2-arg open in favour of 3-arg open.

Comment: Yes, both good points; but the overall structure of "declare hash, open file file, explicit loop, close file" seems basically plausible?

Comment: Well yeah. Those are the things that have to happen regardless of language.

Comment: All of them indeed need to happen, but can be more or less explicit.  For instance, one could imagine GC closing the file for you, and one could imagine the loop being implicit, as in `my @lines = <FILE>;` ... I was looking for tricks along those lines

Comment: The file does get closed implicitly. This does mean no error checking, but it's rarely done for reading anyway. You didn't, for example. And you can easily replace an explicit loop statements with something else. (e.g. I used map and for statement modifier like in my solutions instead of a loop statement). Speaking of error checking, `use autodie;` can help with that. (You still need an explicit `close` statement for `autodie` to kick in for that, though.)

Comment: But then, why bother opening the file. Just pass it as an argument. `my %set; ++$set{ s/\s+\z//r } while <>;`. Now we have no open. No close. No loop statement.

Comment: Very tempting actually ... but there is other command-line parsing going on that this would trip over unless I messaged the ARGV array first.  In fact, I want to do a similar loop three times; once with a real file and twice with piped output from a command.  (Now THAT is quite low-friction in Perl! ... just add `|` to `open` and now you have a sub-process `:)`)

Comment: Better way to launch only one copy of the script (if you don't need to distinguish the inputs): `( cat foo; prog1; prog2 ) | script`

Comment: No, the script very much cares to distinguish the inputs.   That would indeed be nice.

Comment: `script foo <( prog1 ) <( prog2 )` provides three file names, two of which are pipes. (bash)

Comment: That indeed works :) but Ideally the script is in charge of figuring out when to run `prog1` and `prog2` and how to invoke them, not the caller

Answer (score 1):

While the existing answers are "very clever", the standard idiom for reading the lines of the files given as command line parameters is as simple as:

```perl
while (<>) {
    print $_;  # line including the EOL (use chomp to remove)
}
```

So to add the line as key to a hash, you'd use `$hash{$_} = "whatever you want";`.
If you opened the file handle as `$fh`, you'd use `<$fh>`instead.

See also "man perlfaq5".

Comment: thanks!  I was looking for clever but nice to see the obvious answer listed explicitly too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# there's a quick way to read a file as an array
open(FILE, "<", "file.txt") or die("couldn't open file $fn");
my @lines = <FILE>;
close(FILE);</code></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**